# Javascript/JQuery: How to redefine something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

Please pardon my "layman language", but I've been working at this for all day. I almost done customizing this but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this. I'm using Soundmanager (playlist). There's this part in the script that reads:

```
thisSound._data = {
          oLink: o, // DOM reference within SM2 object event handlers
          oLI: oLI,
          oControls: self.select('controls',oLI),
          oStatus: self.select('statusbar',oLI),
          oLoading: self.select('loading',oLI),
          oPosition: self.select('position',oLI), // HERE IT IS
          .......

        };
```

(This is what is setup after the page has finished loading):

```
controlTemplate = document.getElementById("my_sounds");
controlTemplate.innerHTML = [

      // control markup inserted dynamically after each page player link
      // if you want to change the UI layout, this is the place to do it.

      '  <div class="controls">',
      '   <div class="statusbar">',
      '    <div class="loading"></div>',
      '    <div class="position"></div>', // HERE'S WHAT "oPosition" IS CONNECTING TOO
      '   </div>',
      '  </div>'

    ].join('\n');
```

Now, I'm not using what Soundmanager has setup for me (`<div class="position">...`), but instead, I have a div somewhere on the page that'd I'd like to be the **"new"** `oPosition` (`<div class="my_new_position_div">...`).

So, in short, I want to have use `my_new_position_div` as my progress bar instead of the other div.

How do you redefine "oPosition" in this Soundmanger script?

full soundmanager script: [page_player.js](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/script/page-player.js)

Comment: I have no knowledge of soundmanager, but it looks like you would just replace `oPosition: self.select('position',oLI)` with `oPosition: self.select('my_new_position_div',oLI)`

Comment: Thansk @ZackNewsham. That was the first thing I tried, but I'm afraid it didn't work. I'm guessing it's because the script creates these divs after the page has loaded (see the `controlTemplate.innerHTML` code block)

Comment: Hmm, that could be it - but it could also be the parent div - is the my_sounds div your creation - or something done by soundmanager?

Comment: @ZackNewsham `my_sounds` is the wrapper (see the `innerHTML` part).. I could just wrap this around the div I'd like to control the progress bar with, but I'm already using it elsewhere on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've erased my previous answer. I realized that wouldn't work a second after I posted it. The reason why is because the _data property is only set when it is first needed in a handleClick event (this is pretty bad coding). I was hoping I could find a way to keep the script in tact as much as possible, so you are not stuck with a patched version of somebody elses' handy work. But now it seems there is no other way non-intrusive way then to just replace the oPosition line with:

```
oPosition: document.getElementById('my_new_position_div');
```

You need to change `<div class="my_new_position_div">` to `<div id="my_new_position_div">` also.

I suggest you place some big comments around this patched code. This will help you or somebody else working on this code to upgrade to newer versions in the future.

Comment: I just knew it would work before even trying it but unfortunatly, it didn't. I'm getting this error in my console `Cannot set property 'oPosition' of undefined`

Comment: It works but dragging the bar doesn't seem to be working. I think I can figure out the rest though. Thanks a bunch :)